# Whats that song on episode 489-500 of Naruto Shippuden

Tags: naruto, music

I just finished Naruto Shippuden and I would like to know what song was playing at the end of 489-500. This song would fit well in my playlist.
I do not want any answers such as ¨Google it¨. This is because I don't want any spoilers for Boruto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Empty Heart" by Anly